# Oracle Live SQL ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis, Running on other compiler

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, create-table

```sql
CREATE TABLE COUNTY(
  NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
  POPULATION int,    
  INFECTIONRATE int,    
  TOTALNUMBEROFINFECTIONS int,    
  TOTALNUMBEROFNEWINFECTIONS int,    
  COUNTRYNAME VARCHAR(255) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES COUNTRY(NAME)
)
```

When trying to run my code on Oracle Live I run into this exception: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

Proper syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE COUNTY (NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
POPULATION int,
INFECTIONRATE int,
TOTALNUMBEROFINFECTIONS int,
TOTALNUMBEROFNEWINFECTIONS int,
COUNTRYNAME VARCHAR(255)  REFERENCES COUNTRY(NAME)  -- without FOREIGN KEY
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either phrase the statement like so, using the inline foreign key declaration syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE COUNTY(
    NAME VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
    POPULATION int,    
    INFECTIONRATE int,    
    TOTALNUMBEROFINFECTIONS int,    
    TOTALNUMBEROFNEWINFECTIONS int,    
    COUNTRYNAME VARCHAR2(255) REFERENCES COUNTRY(NAME)
);
```

Or you can use the following syntax, which lets you choose the name of the constraint you create:

```
CREATE TABLE COUNTY(
    NAME VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
    POPULATION int,    
    INFECTIONRATE int,    
    TOTALNUMBEROFINFECTIONS int,    
    TOTALNUMBEROFNEWINFECTIONS int,    
    COUNTRYNAME VARCHAR2(255),
    CONSTRAINT FK_COUNTRY FOREIGN KEY (COUNTRYNAME) REFERENCES COUNTRY(NAME)
);
```